# Sending data from activity to multiple fragments with SectionStatPageAdapter and bundle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bundle

I have an activity from where I want to sent the same data to multiple fragments. After the user navigates to the activity there are 3 fragments he will access when he clicks on the buttons to open the next fragment.

So this is what I want:

User opens activity, which has some data --> User gets to first Fragment, which should get the data from the activity --> user gets to 2nd fragment which should have also the data from the activity etc.

I tried using the Bundle approach but I get an NullPointerException when trying to retrieve the data.

Here is my activity:

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SectionsStatePagerAdapter mSectionsStatePagerAdapter;
    LockableViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String usernamePlayer2 = intent.getStringExtra("username player 2");
        String uidPlayer2 = intent.getStringExtra("uid player 2");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("username player 2", usernamePlayer2);
        bundle.putString("uid player 2", uidPlayer2);

        FragmentCategory fragobj = new FragmentCategory();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

        mSectionsStatePagerAdapter = new SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    }

    // ViewPager for the fragments
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        SectionsStatePagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentCategory(), "FragmentCategory1");             // 0
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentQuestion1(), "FragmentQuestion1");            // 1
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentAnswer1(), "FragmentAnswer1");                // 2

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void setViewPager(int fragmentNumber){
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(fragmentNumber);
    }
```

And here is my first Fragment with the NullpointerException:

```
public class FragmentCategory extends Fragment {

    private View btnNavFragCat1, btnNavFragCat2, btnNavFragCat3;
    private TextView tvCategory1, tvCategory2, tvCategory3;
    private ImageView imageCategory1, imageCategory2, imageCategory3;

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestoreCategory = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference categoryCollectionRef = firebaseFirestoreCategory.collection("Categories");

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String usernamePlayer2 = this.getArguments().getString("username player 2");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_category_selection, container, false);


...
        return view;
    }
}
```

I know that with Bundle I only can sent the data from the activity to one Fragment but why do I get the error? And is there a better approach to send the data to multiple Fragments. Right now I would sent it to the first Fragment and from there to the next etc.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly** remove the white spaces between intent keys

> > "username player" => "username_player"

**Secondly** you can access the intent from your fragments by calling

```
getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("username_player")
```

**Finally** make sure you pass the expected intent values while starting the activity

Comment: Thank you for your help, this worked. But why do I have to remove the white spaces?

Comment: Because it's an identifier. A name meant to be a single entity/word not a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same data, the Player, I would do the following:

1. Create a Repository that will store the Player data.
2. Then for each Fragment I would create a ViewModel, with the lifeCyclerOwner being the Fragment.
3. In that ViewModel I would add a LiveData for the Player, and in the init function of the ViewModel I will ask the repository for the data.
4. Then the fragment should observe that LiveData and do something with it in the UI.

Regarding your NullpointerException i think the problem is that the new fragment does not contain the arguments you are trying to extract.